# Strange results calculating Fibonacci numbers

Tags: julia

I wrote a small programm to calculate Fibonacci numbers efficiently in a dynamic way:

```
function fib3(n)
    if n < 2
        return n
    else
        a = 0
        b = 1
        c = 0
        for i=2:n
            c = a + b
            a = b
            b = c
        end
        return b
    end
end
for n=1:110
    println(n,"\t",fib3(n))
end
```

I get a strange result for big numbers:

```
90  2880067194370816120
91  4660046610375530309
92  7540113804746346429
93  -6246583658587674878
94  1293530146158671551
95  -4953053512429003327
96  -3659523366270331776
97  -8612576878699335103
98  6174643828739884737
99  -2437933049959450366
100 3736710778780434371
```

What is the problem? Something with the types?

Comment: Use `BigInt`s if you want to calculate huge integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#integers) try to find the appropriate range under "The minimum and maximum representable values" :)

Apparently, your installation is 64bit and, as that page says, literals are Int64 by default and when an overflow occurs you observe "a wraparound behavior". In other words, 4660046610375530309+7540113804746346429 exceeded the maximum value represented by a signed 64bit-integer (2⁶³-1) so the next number in the sequence appeared negative. This is still a Fibonacci number, but modulo 2⁶⁴ and wrapped around into the negative domain.